# What is the word for the combined senses of an organism?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm having difficulty recalling the word for the unique sensory space of an organism. Or it might be the word for the impression derived from those unique senses, I'm not totally sure. It would be used as follows:

*The human ______ is comprised of sight, smell, taste, touch and sound, and differs from the ______ of a bat.*

I believe I encountered it in Valentino Braitenberg's "Vehicles: Experiments in Synthetic Psychology."

Comment: I would say sensory apparatus or system, or how about sensorium?

Comment: I could use sensory apparatus, but I would prefer the single word. 

I think it was a German word with no English equivalent. (I realize it's disingenuous to ask on an English forum about a German word, if it is in fact German...)

Comment: My German dictinary says this: *Sensorium {n}; Empfindungsvermögen {n}; Sinnesapparat {m}.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a single noun: **[sensorium](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sensorium)**.

> sen·so·ri·um
>   1. a part of the brain or the brain itself regarded as the seat of sensation.
>   2. the sensory apparatus of the body.

Comment: Great, this definitely works for my purposes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Miles: At your service!

Comment: Cf Mat. Beare, MD 1710 **[The Sensorium: a Philosophical Discourse of the Senses](http://books.google.com/books?id=cgIAAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq="sensorium")**

Answer (score 0):

<s>The</s> Human **perception** is comprised of sight, smell, taste, touch and sound, and differs from <s>the ______ of a bat</s> that of a bat.

OED: **perception**

> **3.a. The process of becoming aware of physical objects, phenomena, etc., through the senses; an instance of this.**
>
> 1736   Bp. J. Butler Analogy of Relig. i. i. 20   *The whole Apparatus of Vision, or of Perception by any other of our Senses.*
>
> 1867   Sci. Amer. Dec. 355/1   *Prof. Tyndall..states that the perception by the ear of musical sounds and the range of hearing in
> general is limited by quite narrow bounds.*
>
> 1913   E. Pound in Poetry Mar. 206   *Don't mess up the perception of one sense by trying to define it in terms of another.*